# Нужно узнать название плагина

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Как называется плагин в котором при нажатии на вкладку изображения начинают плавно меняться местами(пример на изображении)?[image: Галерея]

Comment: приложите ссылку на этот сайт, по картинке неясно как именно должно меняться изображение

Comment: картинку я из psd макета вырезал. Вот ссылка на похожий сайт https://www.templatemonster.com/ru/demo/67873.html. Эта функция находится в вкладке portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в коде ясно видно что это плагин:
// MixItUp plugin
// http://mixitup.io